# Find $ \vec{z} \parallel \vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}-\vec{z} \perp \vec{x}$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> For $\vec{x},\vec{y} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\vec{x},\vec{y} \neq \vec{0}$ find $\vec{z} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $\vec{z}\parallel\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}-\vec{z} \perp \vec{x}$.

I started with the dot product:
$$
\begin{align}
\vec{y}-\vec{z} \perp \vec{x} &\Leftrightarrow (y_1-z_1)x_1+(y_2-z_2)x_2=0\\
\vec{z} \parallel \vec{x} &\Leftrightarrow \vec{z}=\alpha \vec{x} \vee \vec{x}=\alpha\vec{z}, \;\, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}
$$

Now I put $\vec{z}=\alpha \vec{x}$ into the first equation:

$$y_1x_1-\alpha x_1x_1 + y_2 \alpha x_2 -\alpha x_2 x_2=0$$

But now I don't know how to proceed. Is my idea correct so far?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a good notion, but you've made an arithmetic error. Your corrected equation is $$y_1x_1-\alpha x_1x_1+y_2x_2-\alpha x_2x_2=0$$ or equivalently $$\vec x\cdot\vec y-\alpha(\vec x\cdot\vec x)=0.$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: thanks a lot, quite easy if I won't think so complicated :)

Comment: No problem. As I said, you were on the right track. Incidentally, the vector $\vec z$ that you found is called the *(orthogonal) projection of $\vec y$ onto (the line spanned by) $\vec x$*, often denoted $$\text{proj}_{\vec x}(\vec y):=\frac{\vec x\cdot\vec y}{\vec x\cdot \vec x}\vec x.$$